# Ember Super Rentals Tutorial 3.15 - Working with data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I was following the ember Super Rental 3.15 tutorial, when I got to the working with data section, I updated the route index file with model hooks, the page stopped working.  Also I am finding ember tutorials to be incomplete.

error says property of map is undefined
code in routes index.js file:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

const COMMUNITY_CATEGORIES = [
  'Condo',
  'Townhouse',
  'Apartment'
];

export default class IndexRoute extends Route {
  async model() {
    let response = await fetch('/api/rentals.json');
    let { data } = await response.json();

    return data.map(model => {
      let { attributes } = model;
      let type;

      if (COMMUNITY_CATEGORIES.includes(attributes.category)) {
        type = 'Community';
      } else {
        type = 'Standalone';
      }

      return { type, ...attributes };
    });
  }
}
```

image if error message:[image]

Comment: Can you alaborate what you find about the "ember tutorials to be incomplete"? What are you missing? Consider to join the [community Discord channel](https://emberjs.com/community/) to explain what you're missing and how the guides could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `fetch('/api/rentals.json');` does not return the correct data. And so when you do `let { data } = await response.json();` then `data` will be `undefined` and you can not do `undefined.map`.

So the code you posted is *correct*. The problem is somewhere else. You can check:

- did you correctly add the `rentals.json` file? If you open `http://localhost:4200/api/rentals.json` do you see the data? So have you done [this](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/working-with-data/#toc_mocking-server-data-with-static-json-files)?
- I see some error from `mirage`. The `super-rentals` tutorial does *not* use `mirage`. I can see this [here](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals/blob/master/package.json) (sidenote: that git repo is automatically *created* from the guides, so its always up to date). So this could be your problem. Depending *how* you configure mirage it will basically mock *all* your `ajax` requests. This means that `fetch(...` will no longer work then expected, mirage assumes you always want to use mocked data and you did not configure mirage correctly. You can try to remove mirage from your `package.json`, rerun `npm install`, restart the `ember server` and try it again.